# How to Update Table with Group by and Sum

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

**Data Table**

```
|id | sysid |

|1  |  938  |

|2  |  938  | 

|3  |   23  |
```

**This is the Update Table I want**

```
|id|amount|sum_amount|
|1 |200| 200+400     |
|2 |400|  400+200    |
|3 |150| 150         |
```

Query :-

```
UPDATE  update_table
SET sum_amount = SUM(amount)
WHERE data_table.id = update_table.id
GROUP BY data_table.sysid;
```

The error was syntax error at or near "Group"

Comment: Why would you want to have a [`GROUP BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) query for an `UPDATE`? This doesn't return any data you could possibly group. It only makes sense in combination with `SELECT` for actually retrieving data .. then you can group it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be a joining of those tables containing a `sum(amount)` aggregation within a subquery and reflecting the result into the update statement through a common table expression :

```
with d as
( 
 select * from
  (
  select d.sysid, sum(u.amount)   
    from data_table d
    join update_table u on u.id = d.id
   group by d.sysid
  ) q1
  right join data_table q2
  on q1.sysid=q2.sysid
)
update update_table u
   set sum_amount = d.sum
  from d
 where u.id = d.id
returning u.*;

id  amount  sum_amount
1   200     600
2   400     600
3   150     150
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ddff1d487a9618f9b588db4d7f0d693d)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

With a CTE which returns the sums:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    sum(amount) sum_amount, 
    ',' || string_agg(cast(d.id as varchar), ',') || ',' ids
  from data_table d inner join update_table u
  on u.id = d.id
  group by d.sysid
)
update update_table u
set sum_amount = c.sum_amount
from cte c
where c.ids like '%,'|| cast(u.id as varchar) || ',%'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=ca8193a3c90d4fef8830180a2725a26b).
Results:

```
> id | amount | sum_amount
> -: | -----: | ---------:
>  1 |    200 |        600
>  2 |    400 |        600
>  3 |    150 |        150
```

Comment: Thank you, I typed something wrong in the question, the update_table doesn't contain sysid so can I use id instead?  And the UPDATE update_table instead of data_table

Comment: Is update_table a different table? If so why do you want to update? You need to insert.

Comment: Yes, It's another different table. I have calculated the amount in the update_table, then I need to sum up the amount based on data_table. I corrected the table in the question.

Comment: Update_table has same rows of id as data_table, I tried your code but end up with the same number for every row. I think because I misguide you on the wrong data source table

Comment: What did you do? You completely changed the schema of the tables?

Comment: When I post the question I put one more column for each table, now these two tables are correct.

Comment: Awesome! The code works, but it also sums up the value where sysid is the null value. Thank you so much!